# Shorebird release ios-alpha fails

Tags: flutter, shorebird

I tried running `shorebird release ios-alpha --flavor staging` to build by iOS application but I'm seeing the following error.

```
✗ Failed to build IPA (309.3s)
    The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to log in with account 'joe@work.com'.
    No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found
    No profiles for 'com.work.ios.staging' were found
```

Here are the [Shorebird docs](https://docs.shorebird.dev/code_push/release) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my xCode session had expired. To fix it, I had to:

1. Open xCode
2. Navigate to Settings -> Accounts
3. Select the email I was using (joe@work.com)
4. Sign in again

After this the shorebird command worked as expected.

Comment: Hay @Code on the Rocks can you upload to app store? Is it Ok for you?